# Why would the |f(x)| be non differentiable for x belonging to Real Numbers?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity, graphing-functions, piecewise-continuity

I'm just started calculus and come across a statement in 1 of my books (*VG Advanced Problems in Mathematics*) that goes like:

*If $y = f(x)$ is differentiable for x belonging to the set of Real numbers, then $y=|f(x)|$ is not differentiable for all x belonging to the set of Real numbers.*

So what I inferred initially is that modulus function are continuous but non differentiable at the point where $f(x)=0$ (where $f(x)=|x|$ ofc) as the left hand derivative and the right hand derivatives are different.

But then I know if $f(x)$ = $|x^3|$ at $x=0$ the left and the right hand derivative would be defined and equal, thus being defined for all x belonging to Real numbers. And moreover $x^3$ is **inside the modulus** ( ***which ummm... is not defined at $f(x)=0$ as modulus functions work that way ?*** ).

In short how can the statement written in my book be correct if $f(x)=|x^3|$ ?

Comment: Your book should  say "... may not be differentiable", not "is not differentiable".

Comment: As written currently, the statement is clearly false. At the very least, if $f$ is always non negative (like for $f(x)=x^2$) then $f$ and $|f|$ are the same function.

Comment: Exactly @Ethan that's is what I was thinking. So perhaps it is wrong to assume that all modulus functions are non differentiable  right? Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Semantic typo: If $y=f(x)$ is differentiable for $x$ belonging to the set of Real numbers, then $y=|f(x)|$
 is differentiable for all $x$ belonging to the set of Real numbers, where $f(x)\neq 0$.

Comment: I check the book. That's not what the book says. You should be clear about the statement of the book.

Comment: @jjagmath Tell me what exactly it says and which page?

Comment: We could have different editions of the book, but in mine it's exercise 31 on page 49, and it's a choice question, not a statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement the book enunciates is completely wrong. The easiest counterexample for it would be any constant function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. As you suggest, the function:
$$f(x) = |x^3| = \begin{cases} x^3 & , x\geq 0 \\ - x^3 & , x<0 \end{cases} $$
, is both continuous and differentiable in the whole real axis.